# Flask - Redirect to a "success" page

Tags: python, flask

i'm new to Flask. And i'm trying to redirect the user to a "success" page where he can download the csv file that my program had create for him.

so my server.py look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, redirect
from flask_cors import cross_origin
import process

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/ind', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost', headers=['Content- Type', 'Authorization'])
 def ind():
    if not request.json:
       abort(400)
    my_json = request.json
    reponse = process.process(my_json)
    if reponse:
       return redirect("http://localhost:8080/success", code=302)
    else:
       return redirect("http://localhost:8080/fail", code=302)


@app.route('/position', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost', headers=['Content- Type', 'Authorization'])
def position():
   if not request.json:
      abort(400)
   my_json = request.json
   reponse = process.process(my_json)
   if reponse:
      return redirect("http://localhost:8080/success", code=302)
   else:
      return redirect("http://localhost:8080/fail", code=302)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)
```

my process.py where the JSON that i received is transformed and transcripts to a csv file, look like this:

```
    def process(my_json):
        [blablabla...]
    return True
```

"reponse" is always True but no redirection, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't see any handlers for the `success` and `fail` routes.

Comment: @LuisOrduz for the views i use react, how can i create this handlers ?

Comment: not sure if this matters, but call to "CORS(app)" seems to be missing

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have handlers for routes `/success` and `/fail`, you can use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for).

```
from flask import url_for

@app.route('/position', methods=['POST'])
def posistion():
    # ...
    if response:
        return redirect(url_for('/success'), code=302)
    return redirect(url_for('/fail'), code=302)
```

Do not hard-code urls to other routes of your flask application. This can lead to your case, when your server is running on port 5050 and your urls are targeting port 8080.

Comment: I'm targeting port 8080 because i use react for my front, and that react app is running on localhost:8080. How can i create the handlers that i need ?